# Error Invoking 'Customize'. Details: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, devexpress

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 I have a popup menu on my designer view where I have added a list of popup menu items. When I try to customize the menu items by clicking on the popup menu and then the customize button. Instead of displaying the popup menu items it displays an error message saying

> Error Invoking 'Customize'`. Details: Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object".

What can I do to solve this? I have no idea what to do. Attached to this is a picture of the error message:

[image]

Comment: Please paste the error message into post, and show the code.

Answer (score 0):

I restarted visual studio and it solved my problem. Hope this helps someone.